# Unable to use script to open Chart Tabs

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am creating a google sheet which shows the performance for a given section. I wanted to create a table of contents page which would allow you to navigate to any page by clicking on a button which has a script tied to it.
I am using the following:

```
function goToSheet(sheetName) {  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}

function goToSheet2() {
goToSheet("Audit Inbound Chart");
}
```

I was intending on creating a similar script for every tab. However this script doesn't work for any sheet that is solely a chart.

By solely a chart I mean that when creating a chart I clicked " Move to Own Sheet" for each graph so it is formatted correctly and the sheet contains only the chart.

The script works fine for everyone of the data sheets, but doesnt work for a single chart sheet.
Is it possible to do this without hyperlinking as I need it to open it without, opening new tabs.

Comment: what is VBA got to do with your code ?

Comment: Apologies, my mistake there.